# Java have thread return something to main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, return

I'm stuck on something, and can't seem to think of a solution. I have a function called dbSelect, which then creates a thread to run a MySQL query and get a `ResultSet`, but then I need my `dbSelect` to get that `ResultSet` and return it. Here's what I have:

```
public class Utils {
    public static void dbSelect(String query){
        selectQuery = query;
        Thread selectThread = new selectThreadClass();
        selectThread.start();
    }
}
class selectThreadClass extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        perform();
    }

    public ResultSet perform(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lob/?user=root&password=");

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(Utils.selectQuery);
            return rs;
        }catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me get it so that `dbSelect` returns the `ResultSet` from the thread? Thanks!

Comment: Don't extend `Thread`, use `Runnable`, extend `Observable` and observe it. There's any number of ways, but that's one that pops to mind. Using Callables with an Executor is another.

Comment: Use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) in conjunction with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You can read more about this in the [relevant Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a try from my end

I modified the code and got the solution using List to hold the value from the ResultSet but I just have one question
and that is, I was not able to get the result as type (ResultSet) in Callable

Somehow the result set was empty when I tried to
retrieve the value using the future get() function

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)future.get();

Below is the piece of code which didnt work,

```
ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Callable<ResultSet> callable = new SelectThreadResultSet();
Future<ResultSet> future = service.submit(callable);
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)future.get();
// Here I dont get any values
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString("EMPLOYEE"));
}
```

Please find below the solution which worked for me, I used List
to hold the values and returned it.

class SelectThreadClass:

```
public class SelectThreadClass implements Callable<List<String>> {

    public List<String> call(){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            rs  = perform();
            while(rs.next()){
                strList.add(rs.getString("EMPNAME"));
            }
            System.out.println("Passed");

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strList;
    }

    public ResultSet perform() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\SqlLite\\EMPLOYEE.db");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Statement s = null;
            try {
                s = conn.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                rs = s.executeQuery(Utils.selectQuery);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rs;
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

class Utils:

```
public class Utils {

    public static String selectQuery = "SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEEDETAILS";
    public static void dbSelect(String query) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, SQLException{
        ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Callable<List<String>> callable = new SelectThreadClass();

        Future<List<String>> future = service.submit(callable);

        List<String> empList = future.get();
        for(String emp : empList){
            System.out.println(emp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, SQLException{
        dbSelect("SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEEDETAILS");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a lot, but I'll try it. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, the solution is simple and the best part is, it works :)

Comment: Sorry I've been a bit busy - I'll test it soon and accept if it works :)

Comment: What data is going into `empList`, because it gives me a `NPI` when trying to print out the items of it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Callable](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6)

```
 public interface Callable<V> {
 V call() throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Runnable Use callable.

```
public class SelectCallableClass implements Callable<ResultSet> {

    public ResultSet call() throws Exception {
        return perform();
    }

    public ResultSet perform(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lob/?user=root&password=");

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(Utils.selectQuery);
            return rs;
        }catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

To submit Callable class, use the ExecuterService

```
ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future future=service.submit(new SelectCallableClass());
```

> The above code does the following(from doc).Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a Future> representing the pending results of the task. The Future's get method
>   will return the task's result upon successful completion.

Comment: Alright, so does this need to be its own file? Also, how will I get my ResultSet, since `future` is calling it?

Comment: future.get() will give you back the return value of the Callable, blocking the calling thread until the Callable has finished executing, and the return value is ready.

Comment: Alright, I'll test ASAP and if it works, accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`run` does not return a result.
Either use al [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) or use a shared variable and poll/`wait` in `Utils` until the result from the `SelectThreadClass` is available.
But I recommend to use a `Callable` as it fits exactly for the task

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have an attribute in your Thread class and then get hold of that attribute,

```
public class Utils {
    public static void dbSelect(String query){
        selectQuery = query;
        Thread selectThread = new selectThreadClass();
        selectThread.start();

        ((SelectThreadClass) selectThread).getResult();
    }
}

class selectThreadClass extends Thread {
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public ResultSet getResult(){
        return rs;
    }

    public void run(){
        rs = perform();
    }

    public ResultSet perform(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lob/?user=root&password=");

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            return s.executeQuery(Utils.selectQuery);
        } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

the only problem is that you might end up handling the connection closure and other stuff out of your dbutil, alternatively , you can convert the result set to whatever java class and then return that java object list rather result set